# Move a child element from shadow dom to light dom on document.ready

Tags: web-component, shadow-dom, custom-element

I defined a custom-element using web componenet:

```
<universal-form>
  <slot name="inner-input">
</universal-form>
```

This custom-element itself is placed inside another shadow dom:

```
<my-dashboard>
  #shadow-root
  <div id="shadow-container">
    <universal-form>
      ...
      <input type="datepicker" id="to-be-exposed" slot="inner-input"/>
    </universal-form>
  </div>
  ...
</my-dashboard>
```

** note: for some of you might suggest putting the `<universal-form>` inside a `slot` of the `<my-dashboard>`, instead of placing it directly into the `<my-dashboard>` shadow-root, this route is ruled out because of some other implementation requirements.

Now I'd like to be able to style the `input#to-be-exposed` from the webpage's css file, so it needs to be accessible from the light dom when the document is rendered ready.

What is some best practice to achieve this?

Comment: Only with a ``<style>`` *inside* the``<universal-form>`` shadowRoot. How and when you create it there is up to you.. or use CSS properties, [CSS ShadowParts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::part) or Constructable StyleSheets (last only supported in Chromium for now) There is no best practice here; it all depends on what/why/when/how **you** want.

Comment: +1 to using Shadow Parts in particular, if all you want is to give full access to styling internal nodes inside a shadow root it's easier to just use CSS than to try to move around the nodes in JS

Answer (score 1):

An option would be to drop the shadowDom form the dashboard element in this case as an element that has a shadow attached doesn't have a light dom visible anymore.

The element won't mind that, things that are leaking in are exactly what you want, namely style from the parent window.

Implementation is simple, instead appending elements to the attached shadow append them directly in to the element.

Example of a shadowless element :

```
class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
   constructor(){
      super();
      this.innerHTML = `elements here`;
   }
}
```

Comment: Is this shadowless method recommeded by the standard?

Comment: There is no standard that regulates what one can put together. Custom Elements, Shadow DOM and the Template are standalone features. One can use just one or all depending on the needs.

Comment: Again this proposed solution is an option, you can achieve the same effect using slotted slots.